# Protect local file with Java

Tags: java

Could anyone help me with protecting local files with Java?

The task is to block other programs from reading/deleting/copying/... specific file. It means only my Java program will be able to modify or read the file (for example `ZIP` file), but the `PC` user will not be able to open the `ZIP` file or do anything with it.

I tried `FileLock` class, but it didn't work, it didn't protect the file at all.

Comment: That would depend on the operating system.  Most do not offer per-program permission, only per-user.  Encryption /signing could protect against reading/faking but not deletion or damage, and only to the degree to which extracting the key from the program is challenging.

Comment: I don't think it would be possible to block all kind of access, because Java gives permission from the OS like other programs and has no right to manage such things!

Comment: I know its not a viable solution, but how about placing the said _ZIP_ file in a folder where the PC user doesn't have read/write permissions ?

Comment: And that folder would be..? I think the PC user can access any place, or not?

Comment: What is the reason behind this urgent need for protection? Sounds a bit like you might be stuck while heading in a wrong direction.